# Powershell apply filter to date hours mins filter

Tags: powershell

Below command runs fine, and give results- using powershell

```
Invoke-DbaWhoIsActive -SqlInstance prod  | Select-object 'dd hh:mm:ss.mss',  login_name, wait_info, host_name, sql_text

dd hh:mm:ss.mss : 00 02:36:54.540
login_name      : sa
wait_info       : 
host_name       : Prod
sql_text        : <?query --
                  begin tran
                  --?>
```

How to apply filter to dd hh:mm:ss.mss - to show results only greater than 15 mins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can parse the `dd hh:mm:ss.mss` property values as [`[timespan]` (`System.TimeSpan`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.TimeSpan) instances, whose `.TotalMinutes` property you can then filter by (via the [`Where-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object) cmdlet):

```
Invoke-DbaWhoIsActive -SqlInstance prod | Where-Object { 
  ([timespan] ($_.'dd hh:mm:ss.mss' -replace ' ', '.')).TotalMinutes -gt 15  
} | Select-Object 'dd hh:mm:ss.mss',  login_name, wait_info, host_name, sql_text
```

The above replaces the space in strings such as `00 02:36:54.540` with a period (`.`), which results in a string that you can cast directly to `[timespan]`.

Comment: I tried to use timespan but I guess I was missing the replace space with period part. Nicely done!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Invoke-DbaWhoIsActive -SqlInstance prod  | Select-object @{n='dd hh:mm:ss.mss';e={if(($_.'dd hh:mm:ss.mss'.tostring().split(" ")[1]).split(":")[0])-gt15){$_.'dd hh:mm:ss.mss'}}},login_name, wait_info, host_name, sql_text
```

Answer (score 0):

What a horrible name for a column header. That said, this should achieve your goal.

```
Invoke-DbaWhoIsActive -SqlInstance prod |
    Where-Object {($_.'dd hh:mm:ss.mss' -split ':')[1] -gt 15} |
        Select-object 'dd hh:mm:ss.mss',  login_name, wait_info, host_name, sql_text
```

Simply splitting the property `'dd hh:mm:ss.mss'` at the colon `:`, grabbing the second element `[1]`, and if it's greater than 15 it will be passed onto your select-object statement.

Here's a little test you can run

```
$var = @'
dd hh:mm:ss.mss
00 02:36:54.540
00 02:12:54.540
00 02:44:54.540
00 02:15:54.540
'@ | convertfrom-csv

$var | Where-Object {($_.'dd hh:mm:ss.mss' -split ':')[1] -gt 15}
```

Comment: But I don't find any difference between the first sample of code and the code I posted, I can only see you have changed the white spaces between the comparison operators, that will not make any difference. btw this is a normal behavior in powershell [grin] used in code golf too much. And also I see you are splitting first by the colon,  that will grab the first two words instead, so the comparison could fail. So I instead will suggest you to first split by the space and select the second one (in array 1), and then split by : and select 0. Welcome

Comment: @WasifHasan (I am not Doug, the OP): The fundamental difference to your solution is that yours doesn't _filter_, the input objects; instead, it reports them all and only _blanks out_ values based on the filter criterion. Also, with the given string format, splitting by `:` alone should work just fine, if only the _2nd_ token is of interest. However, there is a conceptual problem that affects your answer too: Given that the first two digits are the _days_,  e.g. `'01 02:00:54.540'` would not be recognized as representing a 15+-minute time span, even though it clearly is (ditto for _hours_)